# Elevator problem with different measures

Tags: probability

> An elevator takes on six passengers and stops at ten floors. We can assign two different equiprobable measures for the ways that the passengers are discharged: (a) we consider the passengers to be distinguishable or (b) we consider them to be indistinguishable. For each case, calculate the probability that all the passengers get off at different floors.

Above is from the book ["First Course in Probability"](https://www.scribd.com/doc/166652779/First-Course-in-Probability-a-K-Sharma).

According to the solution

a) $\frac{6!}{10^6}{10 \choose 6}$

b) $\frac{10 \choose 6}{15 \choose 6}$

I understand (a) because that is just choose 6 of the 10 floor for the 6 passengers and we can get all the possible permutation among the 6 passenger.

For (b), I don't really understand. What is a good interpretation of indistinguishable passenger and how can I can $15 \choose 6$ in the denominator?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: thank you, will keep that in mind

Comment: As an aside, the problem explicitly states that the outcomes in the sample space for each interpretation are going to be explicitly assumed to be equally likely to occur (*"we can assign two different equiprobable measures...*").  This may be a fine assumption for a problem on paper, but please remember that such as assumption in real life not always ideal.  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery, you either win or you lose, but the probability of winning when playing is certainly not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Indistinuishable passengers" means that a possibility is uniquely determined by the number of passengers assigned to each stop. E.g., let A,B,C,D,E,F be the people and 1, ..., 10 the floors, then

$A,B,C\mapsto 2; D,E\mapsto 5, F\mapsto 7$

and

$C,E,F\mapsto 2; A,B\mapsto 5, D\mapsto 7$

count as different solutions in the labelled problem (when passengers are distinguishable) but they are counted as the same solution of the unlabelled problem (when passengers are all twins).

The easiest way to explain the formula in b) is if we say that we have to choose 6 (floor) numbers out of 10 by repetition: we choose a number as many times as the number of people that get out at that stop. 
There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ ways to chose $k$ objects with repetition out of $n$. 
Out of these $\binom{15}{6}$ options, exactly those $\binom{10}{6}$ are the good solutions where there was no repetition.

Comment: thank you, I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, we only care how many passengers get off at each floor, not which passengers they were.  This is the meaning of "indistinguishable."

As to the solution, it comes from [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).